# Overlaying Text On Top Of A Checkbox On Android

Tags: android, android-studio, checkbox

I want to make a custom checkbox for my Alarm clock app, to match the days of the week. When unchecked, it would display the letter of the day of the week; when checked, it would show the letter in a circle. If needs be, I can always make a vector image of each state for each of the days; but it seems that if possible, it would be much more simple and useful to be able to superimpose the text over top of the checkbox image. On researching, it seems people used to have problems with this happening on accident when setting the padding to 0, but this was fixed and is no longer an option.

Does anybody know if there is currently a way to accomplish this by design? Another option I thought of is doing this in a normal button and adding checked functionality, but this seems like taking a step backwards and reinventing the wheel. Any thoughts?

Comment: Where is design ?

Answer (score 0):

It was so obvious in retrospect, it makes me regret how long I spent Googling it. A negative paddingStart will move the text back over the chechbox, but will cut off the end of the checkbox - at least in the GridView it was a part of. Adding a paddingEnd sufficient to counterbalance it pushed the grid back to the right so it wasn't cutting off the end of the checkbox.